# intermediary model to extends laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, extends

- Hello, this is my first post in stack overflow. If i made any typo or type something wrong, im very sorry for the bad english.
- So i have this stiuation : I have 1 table user have id, parent_id and every other table have user_id. So when the user with parent_id = 0 can see all the activities that other user have that user id as parent_id.

## Problem 1 :

If the user A has parent_id = 0 query to like example : product table,  i want to get all product that have user A id and all product with any other user that has parent_id = user A id.

Table users :
[table user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHF4n.png)

Table econtracts :
[econtracts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2vVb.png)

I can handle problem 1.

## Problem 2 :

Because problem 1 exists like that so that every model i need to do based on problem 1. So now i need an intermediary model to extend laravel model to custom every method that laravel model offer. Currently stuck on get() and paginate().

What i need is replace the laravel model so when i create model i can extends that custom model for my model.
The logic is when i query using query builder or eloquent, if i using paginate() or all() or get() i want to include problem 1 in that query without touch core framework.

Thanks for reading this !

Comment: It will be better if you share both tables and there relationship or paste the model files. 
Second for intermediary model there pivot table concept. 
Link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns

Comment: Thks for reply but im not need a pivot table. What i need is replace the model logic laravel extends for each model i created.

Comment: You can create trait class then use it in your model.